# jQuery - .change() not triggering after selecting image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, microsoft-edge

I am writing a piece of code that loads image and shows the image preview in an    `<img>` tag, it works perfectly on chrome and Firefox but not on Microsoft Edge.  I did a very intensive search but could not find any relevant solution, maybe someone had a similar issue that I did not find online. Anyway, when I do console.log trying to debug the issue, found that the .change() did not work. (Note, It loads a small jpeg image about 20 KB, but it will not work if it is bigger than 25 KB, and need to try at least 2 times then it will load small image)  Here are the files

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {     
$('.img_upload img').bind("click" , function () {   
     var img=$(this);
     var input=img.next(".send_photo_input");
 input.trigger("click");
 input.change(function(){
         console.log("trigger the input");                   
         var preview= $(".send_photo_img");

       var file=document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
        var reader=new FileReader();            
       reader.addEventListener("load",function(){
          console.log("this is before preview");

         preview.attr("src",reader.result);

           console.log("after preview");                

       },false);  //end of the listening           
       if(file)
       {
           console.log("inside if");
           reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       }
       else
       {
           console.log("inside else");
       }        
    });

 });

});
```

The above file is ex1.js

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="ex.css">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ex1.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <div class="img_upload">
           <img class="send_photo_img" id="send_photo1_img" src="left.png"/>
           <input id="send_photo1" name="send_photo1" class="send_photo_input" 
    type="file"/>
       </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

the ex.css is just  with display:none to hide input element

It does not on on Microsoft Edge. I have been debugging this issue, need some help to figure it out, thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting. If you log `input`, are you getting a selector match in Edge? Per your comment on the answer below, `.on("change")` would be the same as `.change`. You might try the `.input` event as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the change event outside the button click event. Code as below:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $('.img_upload img').bind("click", function () {
                var img = $(this);
                var input = img.next(".send_photo_input");
                input.trigger("click");
            });
            $(".send_photo_input").change(function () {
                console.log("trigger the input");
                var preview = $(".send_photo_img");

                var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
                    console.log("this is before preview");

                    preview.attr("src", reader.result);

                    console.log("after preview");

                }, false);  //end of the listening           
                if (file) {
                    console.log("inside if");
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("inside else");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
       #send_photo1{
           display:none;
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="img_upload">
        <img class="send_photo_img" id="send_photo1_img" src="../Images/Capture.PNG" />
        <input id="send_photo1" name="send_photo1" class="send_photo_input"
               type="file" />
    </div>
</body>
```

The result as below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  It works like a charm.  I ended up add some code to the real script to load array of images.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `on`

```
input.on('change',function(){
//rest of the code
})
```

Comment: Actually I think that doesn't make any difference, since    `on('change')` does the same work as     `.change`. Please correct if wrong.

Comment: I tried that @my 1st debug but it does not work. feel like there is something (an event)between click and change. could not figure out